# Can I marshal a C-struct with a 2d array without using "unsafe"?

Tags: c#, c, marshalling, com-interop, unsafe

I have a C DLL that I'm writing a C# interop class for.

In the C DLL, one of the key methods fills a 2d structure; the structure is allocated and freed by helper methods, like so:

```
// Simple Struct Definition -- Plain Old Data
typedef struct MyPodStruct_s
{
    double a;
    double b;
} MyPodStruct;

typedef struct My2dArray_s
{
    MyPodStruct** arr; // allocated by Init2d;
                       // array of arrays.
                       // usage: arr[i][j] for i<n,j<m
    int n;
    int m;
} My2dArray;

void Init2d(My2dArray* s, int n, int m);
void Free2d(My2dArray* s);

// fill according to additional work elsewhere in the code:
void Fill2dResult(My2dArray* result);
```

Simply marshaling `My2dArray.arr` as a pointer to a pointer looks like an issue. **Is there any way I can marshal this for C#, so that I *don't* need the C# code to be unsafe?**
(I'd strongly prefer to avoid modifying my C API if possible, or at least keeping the changes minimal, but this is an option if it's the only way.)

Here's the unsafe C# code I have presently (simplified slightly from the real thing). It works fine and does what I want, but requires unsafe usage:

```
class FooInterop
{
    public struct MyPodStruct // Plain Old Data
    {
        public double a;
        public double b;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private unsafe struct unmanaged2d
    {
        public MyPodStruct** arr;
        public int n;
        public int m;
    };

    [DllImport("Foo.DLL", EntryPoint = "Init2d", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void unsafe_Init2d(ref FooInterop.unmanaged2d, int n, int m);
    [DllImport("Foo.DLL", EntryPoint = "Free2d", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void unsafe_Free2d(ref FooInterop.unmanaged2d);
    [DllImport("Foo.DLL", EntryPoint = "Fill2dResult", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void unsafe_Fill2dResult(ref FooInterop.unmanaged2d);

    public static FooInterop.MyPodStruct[,] Fill2dResult()
    {
        unmanaged2d unsafeRes = new unmanaged2d();
        FooInterop.MyPodStruct[,] res;

        unsafe_Init2d(ref unsafeRes, n, m); // I have n, m from elsewhere
        unsafe_Fill2dResult(ref unsafeRes );
        res = new FooInterop.MyPodStruct[n,m];

        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<m; ++j)
            {
                unsafe
                {
                    res[i, j] = unsafeRes.arr[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        unsafe_Free2d(ref unsafeRes );

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote... with C# 7.0 can you `ref return` a `Marshal.ReadInt32`? (or in general, can you create a managed ref return value from an address?)

Comment: It *might* be useful to show the C function that allocates the 2D array.  Maybe anyone who can't infer the layout from the C# access won't be able to answer your question, but I'm not sure about that.  (Since instructing the marshaller and using unsafe are two different skill sets, technically)

Comment: @zzxyz : Hmmm, interesting. I was hoping that keeping the allocation opaque would simplify matters, not complicate them. For what it's worth: the allocation itself _is_ hidden under the API, so I'm happy to change that, if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Ziv - What I can't quite remember is whether your 2D array is contiguous, or an actual pointer to an array of pointers.  I believe it must be the latter since otherwise your C# code would need the "width" to make sense of `[i][j]` ... == (`[i*width + j`) for contiguous memory.

Comment: You'll be much ahead if you let the C# code create the array.  That avoids having to copy the array content, the native code can write directly to the managed array.  You'd then declare the field as IntPtr and use GCHandle to pin the array.  Doesn't make it safe, but easy enough to make it correct.

Comment: If not the function, you should show the actual C type definitions. Since we're dealing with pointers here and marshaling, we would need to know the exact size and layouts for these objects.

Comment: @JeffMercado : The C-type definitions I brought here are the ones I'm using; I've just foobar'd the names.

Comment: I guess what I was looking for ultimately is the layout of the array as @zzxyz was wondering. If it's a flat contiguous array array vs an array of pointers. You could let the marshaller do all the work, but you need to know the exact layout as it is in memory to get it right.

Comment: @JeffMercado It's an array of pointers (I'm not sure a `MyPodStruct**` could be otherwise, without some legerdemain). Definitely not the most efficient, but in this instance my priority is for the API to be as simple and clear as possible.

Comment: Sorry, not exactly what I meant. It's meant to represent a 2d array. So is that backed by a single array doing pointer math to index into it (`arr[i*width + j]`)? Or is it an array of arrays (`arr[i][j]`)?

Comment: @JeffMercado : Ah! I see the ambiguity now. It's the second, an array of arrays. (I'll edit to clarify.)

Answer (score 2):

Mmmmh... I'll post some code, that probably you don't need :-)

I'm using the latest compiler (C# 7.0) ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers)) plus an unsafe library ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/)).

The point here is that I don't want to marshal by copy the `Unmanaged2d` struct, nor I want to copy the array. I want to use them "in place". I'll use the `ref return` plus some `Unsafe.As*` methods to read the single `MyPodStruct` when asked, and a bidimensional indexer to hide everything. sadly the `Unsafe.As*` require the `unsafe` keyword, because its methods accept `void*` instead of accepting `IntPtr`.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 16)]
public struct MyPodStruct // Plain Old Data
{
    public double a;
    public double b;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Unmanaged2d
{
    public IntPtr arr;
    public int n;
    public int m;

    public unsafe ref MyPodStruct this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            if (x < 0 || x >= n)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(x));
            }

            if (y < 0 || y >= m)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(y));
            }

            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(arr, x * sizeof(IntPtr));
            IntPtr ptr2 = ptr + y * 16; // 16 == sizeof(MyPodStruct)
            return ref Unsafe.AsRef<MyPodStruct>(ptr2.ToPointer());
        }
    }
}

unsafe_Init2d(ref unsafeRes, n, m);

// We increase all the values of a and b, just to show that we can!
for (int i = 0; i < u.n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < u.m; j++)
    {
        u[i, j].a += 10;
        u[i, j].b++;
    }
}

// We print them
for (int i = 0; i < u.n; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", Enumerable.Range(0, u.m).Select(x => string.Format($"({u[i, x].a},{u[i, x].b})"))));
}
```

As a sidenote, it seems that using `IntPtr` to make "unsafe" code "safe" is getting frowned upon. See for example [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18946#issuecomment-297579578) where a request for an overload to `Span<T>(void*)` that accept a `Span<T>(IntPtr)` and has been closed because:

> We want operations with pointers to be explicit operation with pointers, and not hide them behind IntPtr that tend to give people a false sense of safety.

and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/18150#issuecomment-392530423).

In general what you want to do can be done with some `Marshal.ReadIntPtr` plus `BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(Marshal.ReadInt64(...))`, like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Unmanaged2d
{
    public IntPtr arr;
    public int n;
    public int m;

    public static MyPodStruct[,] Fill2dResult()
    {
        Unmanaged2d unsafeRes = new Unmanaged2d();

        //unsafe_Init2d(ref unsafeRes, n, m); // I have n, m from elsewhere
        //unsafe_Fill2dResult(ref unsafeRes);

        MyPodStruct[,] res = new MyPodStruct[unsafeRes.n, unsafeRes.m];

        for (int i = 0; i < unsafeRes.n; i++)
        {
            IntPtr row = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(unsafeRes.arr, i * IntPtr.Size);

            for (int j = 0, offset = 0; j < unsafeRes.m; j++)
            {
                // Automatic marshaling of MyPodStruct
                // res[i, j] = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MyPodStruct>(row + j * (sizeof(double) + sizeof(double)));

                // Manual marshaling

                // a
                long temp1 = Marshal.ReadInt64(row, offset);
                double dbl1 = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(temp1);
                offset += sizeof(double);

                // b
                long temp2 = Marshal.ReadInt64(row, offset);
                double dbl2 = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(temp2);
                offset += sizeof(double);

                res[i, j] = new MyPodStruct { a = dbl1, b = dbl2 };
            }
        }

        //unsafe_Free2d(ref unsafeRes);

        return res;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't technically contain anything that is `unsafe`, but it is as much unsafe as your code.

Ah... and in C#, what you have in C is called a jagged array. It is an array of arrays (a first level of arrays of pointers that point to many second level arrays of elements). It isn't a multidimensional array.

Comment: Thank you! This is something I didn't know how to do. If I understand you correctly, this means making the `MyPodStruct**` member an opaque pointer, and manually interpreting that memory, according to the underlying array-of-arrays structure. (I come from C/C++, where this would be like using `void*` and then casting to the real type...)

Comment: @Ziv Yes. Note that in the first example the original array is read upon request, while in the second example the original array is immediately copied to managed memory.