# Marshal a struct containing pointer to array

Tags: c#, pointers, struct, marshalling

How to correctly marshal this C struct with pointer to array and pointer to pointer members in C# for use with 3rd party dll?

**C:**

```cpp
typedef struct SomeStruct {
    uint8_t *data[8];
    int size[8];
    uint8_t **extended_data;
};
```

Is it all just `IntPtr` and then you need to allocate the un-mamaged memory, copy data into it, and pin it? How would you do this if it's the case? The struct gets initialized through a function inside dll.

In python this is how I'd wrap and use this struct:

**Python:**

```py
class SomeStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
         ('data', POINTER(c_uint8) * 8),
         ('size', c_int * 8),
         ('extended_data', POINTER(POINTER(c_uint8)))
    ]

# example use 1
dll = ctypes.CDLL("lib.dll")
some_struct = SomeStruct()
dll.init_struct(ctypes.byref(some_struct))

# or example 2
alloc_struct_fce = dll.alloc_struct
alloc_struct_fce.restype = ctypes.POINTER(SomeStruct)   # specify return type
some_struct_ptr = alloc_struct_fce()    # this gets passed to other dll functions
dll.some_processing(some_struct_ptr)
some_struct = some_struct_ptr.contents    # dereference the pointer
```

Trying to find a C# equivalent of this code.

`extended_data` is a bonus if you know how to deal with it, it's dynamic size and I am not sure how I'd get its size.

A real example would be

- [struct AVFrame](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/c8e1e56509c3f176803cdf40b4019263125fa43f/libavutil/frame.h#L314) together with [AVFrame *av_frame_alloc(void)](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/c8e1e56509c3f176803cdf40b4019263125fa43f/libavutil/frame.c#L190)
- [struct AVPacket](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/c8e1e56509c3f176803cdf40b4019263125fa43f/libavcodec/packet.h#L340) with [void av_init_packet(AVPacket *pkt)](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/c8e1e56509c3f176803cdf40b4019263125fa43f/libavcodec/avpacket.c#L35) and [AVPacket *av_packet_alloc(void)](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/c8e1e56509c3f176803cdf40b4019263125fa43f/libavcodec/avpacket.c#L53)

The .dll provides methods to allocate and free these structures.

Comment: It depends on who allocates the memory pointed by `data` and `extended_data`. The caller (C#) or the callee (the dll). If it is the callee (the dll), then `IntPtr`, if it is the caller, perhaps you could pass around `byte[][]`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The code is using the Windows Allocate method and see following for equivalent c# code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=net-5.0.  You are reading the data so what is the size of the extended data?  Usually structure like this the first number is the length of the second number the extended data.

Comment: @jdweng yes the struct has record of size of each of the 8 arrays. I updated the question. Not sure with the `extended_data` though.

Comment: @xanatos it's the callee (the dll). I suspect it's `IntPtr`, the trouble I am facing is with getting the contents of such struct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611261/11683?

Answer (score 1):

I woul use following code which is based on xanatos code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"somedll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl /* or StdCall */)]
        public static extern void SomeStructMethod(out SomeStruct someStruct);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeStruct someStruct;
            SomeStructMethod(out someStruct);

            byte[] data = new byte[8];
            Marshal.Copy(someStruct.data, data, 0, 8);

            byte[][] extendedData = new byte[8][];
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                extendedData[i] = new byte[someStruct.size[i]];
                Marshal.Copy(someStruct.extended_data[i], extendedData[i], 0, someStruct.size[i]);

            }
        }
    }
  
    struct SomeStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public IntPtr data;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public int[] size;

        public IntPtr[] extended_data;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your struct, we could:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public IntPtr[] data;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public int[] size;

    public IntPtr extended_data;
}

// I don't know the calling convention of your C method... You didn't show
// us its signature. It could be cdecl or stdcall
[DllImport(@"somedll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl /* or StdCall */)]
public static extern void SomeStructMethod(out SomeStruct someStruct);
```

Then:

```
SomeStruct someStruct;
SomeStructMethod(out someStruct);

for (int i = 0; i < someStruct.data.Length; i++)
{
    var array = new byte[someStruct.size[i]];
    Marshal.Copy(someStruct.data[i], array, 0, array.Length);

    Console.Write("> ");

    for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write($"{array[j]} ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Note that at the end you should call some C method to free the memory allocated in `someStruct` otherwise you'll have a memory leak!**

I can't help you about `extended_data`, because you haven't told us what it should be,

Comment: Coming from python this is all confusing, because every example is handled a little differently and there are so many online but not one quite like mine. Thanks, it really helps me to start understand how it all works and why it is so dependent on the .dll code. I've updated the question to provide real example, I think the calling convention is Cdecl.